# SimpleModal, How to close pop up window with animation

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am very new to jQuery. I have a questino about the SimpleModal.

I am trying to close the pop up window with animation effect, but failed.

Here is my code.

```
 $('#btnClose').click(function(e) {
            // Closing animations
            $("#content").modal({ onClose: function(dialog) {
                dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    dialog.container.hide('slow', function() {
                        dialog.overlay.slideUp('slow', function() {
                            $.modal.close();
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
            });

        });
<div id="content" style="display: none;">
    <h1>Basic Modal Dialog</h1>
    <a href='#' id="btnCloset">Close</a>
</div>
```

When I click on the "Close" link, nothing happens. Any help please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, which is working perfectly.

```
$('#btnOpen').click(function(e) {
            $('#content').modal({
                onOpen: function(dialog) {
                    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function() {
                        dialog.data.hide();
                        dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function() {
                            dialog.data.slideDown('slow');

                        });
                    });
                },
                onClose: function(dialog) {
                    dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        dialog.container.slideUp('slow', function() {
                            dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function() {
                                $.modal.close(); // must call this!
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            });

        });
        $('#btnClose').click(function(e) {
            $.modal.close();

        });
```

Answer (score 3):

**Original, accepted answer**

Nothing is happening because you misspelled `btnClose` in your HTML id tag (you're calling it **`btnCloset`**). Nonetheless, it wouldn't work with the provided code, as this is what it does: When you click on the `btnClose` link, you are creating a simpleModal box out of `#content`, and telling it that when it closes, it should do the stuff in the `onClose` option (which is correct). So you aren't actually telling it to close anywhere, just telling it that it's a modal dialog.

Instead you should create the modal out of the `#content` element, as you do now, but do it separately from `#btnClose`'s click event. Then you should bind click event to close the dialog.

Here's some code

```
$(function() {
    /* Make #content a modal */
    $("#content").modal(
     {
        onClose: function(dialog) {
            dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                dialog.container.slideUp('slow', function () {
                    dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                        $.modal.close(); // must call this!
                    });
                });
            });

        }
     }
    );

    /* When #btnClose is clicked, close the modal */    
    $('#btnClose').click(function(e) {
        $.modal.close();
    });
});
```

---

As a side note, if you add the class `simplemodal-close` to `#btnClose`, simpleModal will automatically make it close the dialog, and you don't have to bind the click event yourself.

**New answer based on feedback**

Ok, i misunderstood how this addon works, i thought it was like the plain jQuery dialog plugin, but as i understand now, the goal is to make an existing, visible element a dialog and when closing it, transform it back to its original form. The new code keeps track of the state of the dialog (by storing `doOpen` in the `data` of the link and toggling it on each click) and both opens and closes the dialog. Hope this is closer to how you wanted it to work :)

```
$(function() {
    $("#btnClose")
    .data("doOpen", true)
    .click( function() {
        /* check whether or not we are to open or close the dialog */
        var doOpen = $(this).data("doOpen");
        /* toggle the data */
        $(this).data("doOpen", !doOpen);

        if (doOpen) {
            $("#content").modal({
                onClose: function(dialog) {
                    dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                        dialog.container.slideUp('slow', function () {
                            dialog.overlay.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                                $.modal.close(); // must call this!
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $.modal.close();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: By following your provided codes, the close event works. However, when I load the page, the modal automatically pop up. Anyway, you give me some clue. Thank you very much.

Comment: And I know I can use the "simplemodal-close", but that one doesn't have the closing animations.

Comment: Ok, i think i misunderstood. Edited my answer. Hope I understood it better now

Comment: Thank you very much Simen Echholt.

Comment: I think for this case, I may use onShow function comes with the simple modal. I am still learning it.

Comment: I posted the working code here. Simply needed to define both onOpen and onClose function together.